# Define a variable in header file works only when extern keyword is not present?

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

I am learning at moment `C` and I really do not understand how header
files works and to be sure I have two Questions.

1) Let's take a look at the following program: main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"


int main( void )
{
    printf( "Num = %d\n", number );
    printNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

functions.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"

void printNumber( void )
{
    printf("Number = %d\n", number );
}
```

functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS
#define FUNCTIONS

int number;
extern void printNumber( void );

#endif // FUNCTIONS
```

The way the program is in the Header file there is no `extern` keyword
involved so there seems to be reference to `number` and the program
Outputs:

```
Num = 0
Number = 0
```

The first Question is, does `number` get initialized (is number global
variable or similar if `number` is present only in the header file) 
and is this a legal code/program?

Second scenario, let's take a look at the following code main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main( void )
{
    printf( "Num = %d\n", number );
    printNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

functions.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"

void printNumber( void )
{
    printf("Number = %d\n", number );
}
```

functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS
#define FUNCTIONS

extern int number;
extern void printNumber( void );

#endif // FUNCTIONS
```

Here the program will not compile due the

```
`undefined reference to number`
```

Which force me to declare `number` in `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"

int number;

int main( void )
{
    printf( "Num = %d\n", number );
    printNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

Which is the Right way and why?
 Last thing, why does exactly not apply
to `void printNumber( void )` as well. I see that it is working with
or without the `extern` keyword.

Comment: Just use `int number;` in the header files; this is a so-called "tentative definition" in your object files, which will cumulate in a single definition at link time. And yes, number gets initialized with 0 as any global variable.

Comment: @Ctx Somehow contradicts the given Answer with your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first version, in your header file, you *define* the variable `number`. That means every [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) that includes the header file will have a definition of the variable. That's not allowed, you can only have a single definition spread over all translation units.

The solution to that problem is to *declare* the variable in the header file instead:

```
extern int number;
```

The use of the keyword `extern` marks this as a declaration instead of a definition, the compiler will know that the variable is defined somewhere else.

Then you of course need to define it somewhere. In *one single* source file put the definition:

```
int number;
```

I.e. exactly what you do in your last variant.

Comment: Well, many toolchains and I think posix allows multiple definitions...

Comment: So this means that if i declare `int number` in main, there is no need to be declared in `functions.c` as well?

Comment: is this same for functions as well or only for variables?

Comment: @MichaelB. Yes if you define it explicitly in `functions.c` you will have the same problem with multiple definitions. And yes it's the same for functions too.

Comment: Never heard of tentative definitions yet?

Comment: So this means that if I use the keyword `extern` for all variables and functions in header files it will be OK. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelB. Functions are `extern` by default, no need to explicitly specify this.You can make them "local" to the translation unit (the .c file) by declaring them `static`.

Comment: @alk I understand. To bad that I can not up vote this Question due the less than 15 rep.

Comment: @MichaelB. No, that's ok, since already the first paragraph is wrong.

Comment: @alk, there is a sloght difference betwen`extern void f(void);` and `void f(void);`. The first is a declaration, the second is a prototype.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The first is only a declaration or it is also a declaration and prototype. I am talking about its presence in Header files.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Some programmer dude*'s answer, I use the following construct:

```
// functions.h
#indef EXTERN
# define EXTERN extern
#endif
EXTERN int number;

// functions.c
#include "functions.h"

// main.c
#define EXTERN
#include "functions.h"
```

When main compiles, storage will be allocated for `number`. In all other source files, it will be declared as `extern`.

Comment: So how can I use a variable in main which is defined in header file, but it will not be seen in other `.c` files? for example if I need `number` to be seen only in `main.c`

Comment: Then define it in main: `static int number;`

Comment: I did already that and I got: `error: static declaration of ‘number’ follows non-static declaration`

Comment: define it ONLY in main. Not in the header anymore.